# CPU Timeout limit exceeded exception caused for existing working code after SF upgraded to Summer'16,. Any idea if anything updated in Summer'16

Tags: apex, governorlimits, timeout, cpulimit, xmlnode

I have a code which was working for my previous packages. But after the Summer'16 release I am getting the CPU timeout exception for my codebase which was working earlier.
Is there any thing update from SF side in summer'16. Because the codebase has not been changed and I suspect something in the release is causing this.

Comment: The cause of CPU time out could be increase in Data also.So probably you need to consider that as well.

Comment: Yes Its considered. But previously also it was working with the same amount of data.

Comment: We are facing the same issue, you able to find the root cause ??

Comment: @AmitKumar Unfortunately no. SF said that they have backend changes to improve quality. We had to handle it our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was raised with SF, and they said they make improvements to limits in backend and don't mention these in release notes. We had to change our entire code flow to handle this

Answer (score 0):

[Summer-16 release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_cross_namespace_limits.htm):

Actually with summer-16 they have improved the other cross-namespaced limits.

> but the Limits that are shared across all namespaces, such as the
>   limit on maximum CPU time, remain the same. The new cumulative limit
>   doesn’t affect these limits.

I don't think there is any direct reason or change which can start causing the CPU timeout exception.Maybe you can provide detail of supporting code sample etc maybe that is helpful

Comment: It will be difficult to provide the whole codebase here. We parse a csv with approx 5k values and create the XForm. The limit which we had provided to our customers was this and it was working fine from last 2 years and now it suddenly stopped working. We didn't even change the codebase.

Comment: It could be possible that they have installed some other packages or they have some custom code written on there side which is adding with your transaction.

Comment: No. Customers have not yet reported this one. We found out this during our testing. And no other packages are installed. We will be optimising our code to handle this but wanted to make sure if Summer'16 has changed something because its the older code working for years with the same amount of data.

Comment: Probably you can check debug logs what components exactly are running in a transaction.